# Failing specific instances in Jenkins flow

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Simplifying my problem:
I'm running a flow in Jenkins (using Groovy file), which should perform 2 jobs.

1. Install some app on different VMs on parallel:

```
build job: 'SomeInstallationJob', parameters: [
    string(name:'paramA',value:paramA),
    string(name:'paramB',value:paramB),             
    [$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'hosts', labels: active_nodes_name_labels, 
        nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]
]
```

2. Run some tests (on the same VMs ofcourse):

```
build job: 'RunSomeTestsJob', parameters: [
    string(name:'paramC',value:paramC),
    string(name:'paramD',value:paramD),             
    [$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'hosts', labels: active_nodes_name_labels, 
        nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]
]
```

The thing is that when one of the VMs fails in the first job, I would like this specific VM to die, and not to move forward to the second job. I currently use 'propagate: false' on the first job, which makes everything continue (unfortunately everything here includes the bad VM). I know that if i'll discard the 'propagate: false', when one of the VMs will fail, the entire flow will fail.

Any ideas how to keep everything's going, but running only on the VMs that passed successfully the first job? Thanks!